# How to read Ruby global variable using internal C API?

Tags: c, ruby

In the README.EXT documentation (which comes with the Ruby platform source), it mentions `rb_define_variable`, which takes a C pointer to `VALUE` and "connects" it to a Ruby global variable, so reading/writing the variable from Ruby-land will access the given location in memory.

But I  need something a little different: from C-land, I want to access global variables which were defined and initialized from within Ruby. I don't need to list all the global variables which are defined -- I just want to access the value of a global variable given its name, and I want to do it from the C side.

If all else fails, I know I can use `rb_eval_string` (which is the same as `eval` in Ruby), but there should be a better way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you want is `rb_gv_get` (itself a wrapper around some of the global variable stuff). With rubyinline you could write

```
require 'inline'
class Foo
  inline :C  do |builder|
    builder.c_raw_singleton <<SRC
      VALUE read_global(VALUE self, VALUE *name){
        return rb_gv_get(rb_string_value_cstr(name));
      }
SRC
  end
end
```

and then

```
$bar = 1
Foo.read_global('bar') #=> 1
```

(rubyinline doesn't work in irb).

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I tried grepping for "global" and "variable" but didn't find anything...